# Deploy dotnet core API and angular in apache 2 server url rewrite rule error

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, .net-core, deployment

I have a project having angular 11 as a front end and Dotnet Core 5 API.

I have to deploy my project in a Ubuntu 20.04 using apache2 web server.

Steps what I followed to deploy and configure the apache server.

Step1: I configured the Forward headers to handle the reverse proxy headers
And in the next line If path is 404, redirecting to index.html page
I used this because I want to deploy the application as a single unit deployment package
Please refer to this link
https://dzone.com/articles/publish-and-deploy-angular-and-net-core-applicatio

```
           app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | 
             ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();
                
                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !System.IO.Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
                {                    
                    context.Request.Path = "/index.html";                   
                }
            });
```

Step2: I installed apache2 server and installed required dotnet packages
Step3: Created a sample.service file in etc/systemd/system directory and enabled it.

systemctl enable sample.service

Step4: Created a sample.config file in etc/apache2/sites-available directory and enabled it.

a2ensite sample.conf

please refer this link https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/hosting-multiple-asp-net-core-apps-in-ubuntu-linux-server-using-apache.aspx

and lastly restarted the apache server.

Everything seems to be working file but If a redirecting the url other than home I am getting 404. Typically url write issue.

If I open [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) -  it works
If I Open [www.example.com/login](http://www.example.com/login) - throwing 404

Later I created the .htaccess file and written url rewrite rules

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/.*$
   RewriteRule . index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

and enabled config file again and restarted the apache2 server

a2ensite sample.conf

But same issue occuring.

My file structure looks like

[File structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/439UY.png)

So I am confusing that where to place the .htaccess file to enable url rewrite rules.
In the root application path like / or inside wwwroot folder.

Or Am I going with the wrong process. Please suggest me if its not a proper way of doing

Help me out with the other ways of doing so.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I simply put my sample.conf file in /etc/apache2/conf-enabled instead of sites-available. Then it worked

Comment: It is common practice to have all site conf files in the `sites-available` directory and create a symlink from `sites-enabled` (or `conf-enabled`?) as required instead of physically copying/moving the file. In fact, this is what the `a2ensite` command _should_ be doing.